# Toggle Layers in OpenLayers does not work?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to make a map in which I can toggle layers on and off in the navigation bar. A simple version of my code is in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TimLucas/3cqsmc2L/

If you click on the button in the nav-bar, the layer should disappear, but for some reason it does not. I am using this type of nav bar since I would like to have sub sub sub menus (this site is not to be used on mobiles).

For some reason I cannot figure out why the toggling does not work, I've been looking for 2 hours now but I cannot find an awnser. The toggeling of the layers does work in the console (if I run the file locallly) so this is probably related to the eventhandler on the navbar.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the *#* at the start of your jQuery [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), line 119 in your jsfiddle, for your *toggle-layers* element.

A neater solution might be to use the [bindTo](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html?unstable=true#bindTo) method between your source layer (vectorLayer) and target element (a checkbox).  See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/bind-input.html as an example